# HTML5 validation with vue.js multi form

Tags: javascript, html, validation, vue.js

I have a vue.js form with multiple form steps that needs html5 validation simplified it looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="activeForm === 1">

            <h2>
                How much does {{ form.name }} weight?
            </h2>

            <text-input
                    v-model="form.weight"
                    name="weight"
                    :errors="form.errors"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="For example: 20 kg"
                    required>
            </text-input>
        </div>

        <div v-if="activeForm === 2">

            <h2>
                Search here
            </h2>

            <select-search></select-search>
        </div>

        <button v-if="activeForm > 1"
                @click="previousForm()">
            Previous
        </button>

        <button @click="nextForm">
            Finish
        </button>
    <div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                activeForm: 1,
                totalForm: 6
            }
        },

        methods: {
            previousForm() {
                if (this.activeForm > 1) {
                    this.activeForm--;
                }
            },

            nextForm() {
                if (this.activeForm < 6) {
                    this.activeForm++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Right now obviously the HTML5 validation is not working. But how could I validate it for every form step any ideas (I want to submit the form with 1 ajax call)?

Comment: Can you not exchange the div with form tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use HTML validation you need to set the type of your *input* tags but that will not be enough because right now the specification only covers some inputs types like: date, email, number, (for number you can set a range with Min and Max). We would need to check your *text-input* component to see why is not working the HTML validation.

If you only need to verify that **each *input*** was **filled** by the user you can add the required attribute to those elements.